# How can I detect the stripe noise of images?

Tags: python, opencv, fft

I try use the methods in the internet, but I can't find a good algorithm, can detect the stripe noise of images effectively. I know some methods about FFT(Fast Fourier Transform Algorithm) to solve this problem, but I don't know the specific method.

Comment: Some sample images for "stripe noise" would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you know you can find the issue using FFT so what are you stuck on? how to FFT? `cv2` and `numpy` both can do that

Comment: I will show some example images, I just know the FFT can solve the problem, but I don't know how to detect  specifically, so can you show me the specific method?

Answer (score 0):

these are two example images.
[stripe_image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4TGV.png)

[stripe_image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Dm6.png)

and these are two normal images(zebra crossing and normal stripe image), I need make some distinguish of normal image. just like our eyes can do.
[normal_image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NioIG.png)

[normal_image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RKz8.png)